# ipmitool does not show serial number

Tags: i2c, ipmi, ipmitool

I want to get the serial number of the server power supply using the ipmitool utility. The utility does not show what was expected.

I request the serial number of the power supply via the ipmitool utility. From bash I send the command:
`ipmitool i2c bus=3 0xb2 0x18 0x9e`
Device address 0xb2, command 0x9e (MFR_SERIAL by specification pmbus), and 0x18 bytes - length of  response.
And get a response:
`14 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 2d 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 b8 00 00`
It doesn't match the serial number.
What was I wrong about, how to correctly request a serial number via ipmitool or directly thru pmbus?